# Java: how to get first floorEntry() in LinkedList w/o traversal. LinkedSortedMap

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, linked-list, sortedmap

I have a list that needs to be traversed in order of insertion. However, i want to find "starting points" by using floorEntry and ceilingEntry on the values.

So I need a collection with the following desired operations:

1. frequent insert/append to end
2. need to traverse like this:

   - find all values >= or <= (floor,ceiling)
   - then traverse this in order of insertion
   - remove each item that matches a criteria

So the collection needs to be sorted in order of insertion, but also need random access based on sorted values.

Is there something like a LinkedSortedMap? But not sure this will work either.

how can I find the first floorEntry() of a value in a linkedlist? 
how can I find all the floorEntries form a linkedlist?

==============in other words==============================

```
//I have timeseries of Ints.
TimeSeries<Int> collection = new LinkedList<>()

/*
FindAndRemove is to remove first n Ints that are <= x
*/

FindAndRemove1(Int x,int n) {
  //return an iter to filtered subset of collection
  iter = collection.floorEntrySet(x) 
  for (int i =0; i<n; i++) {  
    iter.remove()   
    if (!iter.hasnext) break; 
    iter->next
}


FindAndRemove2(Int x,int n) { 
   //return an collection.iter to oldest Int that is <= x
   iter = collection.floorEntry(x) 
   for ( int i = 0; iter.hasnext; iter.next ) {  
      if ( iter.x > x ) 
        continue;

      iter.remove()
      if ( ++i > n ) break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to support removals, then you can use a TreeMap where the key is an auto-incremented integer

```
TreeMap<Integer, Object> sortedMap;
HashMap<Object, Integer> lookupMap;
int key;

public void add(Object obj) {
    sortedMap.put(key, obj);
    lookupMap.put(obj, key);
    key++;
}
```

Use lookup map to find an object's key in the sorted map, and then perform a floor/ceiling query on the sorted map using the retrieved key.

Google has a [HashBiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html) that you might be able to adapt to suit your needs by using a hash map in one direction and a tree map in the other direction

Comment: wont work. the collection needs to be sorted by time.... but i need to do lookup based on value and not time.

Comment: ok - looks better. but will have to do floor on lookupMap, so lookupMap will have to be a SortedMap. maybe i need to edit my question to clarify.

Comment: HashBiMap does not have a floorEntry. would need a SortedBiMap.. hmm maybe BiMap..